# What is the right set notation for this setup.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am considering a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of dimension $N \times M$. Each element of $\mathbf{A}$ is $a(n,m) \in \{+1,-1\}$. What is the compact way of writing this matrix

**My attempt:**

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\{a(n,m)| a(n,m)=\{+1,-1\}, 1\leq n\leq N,1\leq m\leq M\}
\end{equation}

Comment: I would write $\mathbf{A}: \{1,\ldots, N\}\times \{1,\ldots, M\} \to \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: ok. One more question. How would you change this notation if $A$ is a matrix with elements that are Bernoulli random variables ?

Comment: $\mathbf{A} : \{1,\ldots,N\}\times \{1,\ldots,M\} \to \mathrm{Bernoulli}$ where $\mathrm{Bernoulli}$ is the set of Bernoulli random variables.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the way you wrote it. It depends on how "compact" you want it. Set-theorists often write $A^B$ to mean the set of all functions from $A$ to $B.$ And I have seen $[[N]]$ to mean $\{n\in \mathbb N: 1\leq n\leq N\}.$ So if you want to represent  $A=(a_{n,m})_{n\leq N, m\leq M}$ as a function you could write $$A\in \{-1,1\}^{[[N]]\times [[M]]}.$$ And then write a paragraph, as I  did, explaining what this means.

Comment: Yes compact notation is what I am looking for. Can you modify this notation for the case when $a(n,m)$ is a Bernoulli RV